# Is it possible for me to know which questions have gained or lost protection by me?

Tags: discussion, protected-questions

In my "activities", I don't see an option for this. Also, couldn't find a meta post for this.

Being relatively new to the "protect" tool, I might've misused it. Now, having learned about it, I'll properly use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is almost certainly only available via a query on the database. The available dataset is updated [weekly on Sundays](http://data.stackexchange.com/help).

Here's one query: http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/449043/my-unprotected-questions Its two authors are both moderators, which lends support to the view that the data is not available by other means.

You'll need to enter a user id in the box before pressing "Run Query": yours is 50044.

Answer (score 3):

The new feature was introduced on Nov. 18, 2016 and you can review a list of protected questions as indicated in the Meta SE post, [Show 10kers a larger list of recently protected questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273882/show-10kers-a-larger-list-of-recently-protected-questions).

> As of this morning (Nov. 18), there is a new 10k tool under `/tools` that provides a list of protected questions.

It's impossible to review unprotected questions unless you use SEDE. You can get some help in the following link, [an answer to Where can I find the list of questions I (un-)protected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310573/where-can-i-find-the-list-of-questions-i-un-protected/310574#310574.) on Stack Overflow Meta.

Note: The following feature request is still pending. [Please add the list of questions (un-)protected to the profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269628/please-add-the-list-of-questions-un-protected-to-the-profile-page)